# What might the term "B-I-T-sweetie" mean in the context of Zora Neale Hurston and Langston Hughes's play "The Mule-Bone"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, african-american-vernacular-english

I am currently reading through Zora Neale Hurston and Langston Hughes's 1931 play, T*he Mule-Bone*, and I am rather puzzled by the term "B-I-T-sweetie," which shows up in this exchange in Act I:

> Walter: (Winking.) Whut’s dat you got, Teet⁠ ⁠… letter from Dave?
>
> Teet: (Flouncing.) Naw indeed! It’s a letter from my **B-I-T-sweetie**! (Rolls her eyes and hips.)
>
> Walter: (Winking.) Well, ain’t Dave yo’ **B-I-T-sweetie**? I thought y’all was ’bout to git married. Everywhere I looked dis summer ’twas you and Dave, Bootsie and Jim. I thought all of y’all would’ve done jumped over de broomstick by now.
>
> Teet: (Flourishing letter.) Don’t tell it to me⁠ ⁠… tell it to the ever-loving Mr. Albert Johnson way over in Apopka.

Teet is a female character, described in the dramatis personae as "Village vamp who is jealous of Daisy." Walter is a male character, described as "Another village wag." I believe the letter is supposed to be from "Mr. Albert Johnson," who does not appear on stage in the play.

For even more context, you can read the play at the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mhurston.0103/?sp=10).

From context clues, I get the sense that it's a term of endearment, but I am really not sure how to parse it. Is "B-I-T" some sort of initialism or acronym, or is this supposed to represent the characters drawing out or spelling out the word "bit"? (Even if "B-I-T" is just the word "bit," I still have no idea what a "bit-sweetie" or "bit sweetie" is. I have never encountered that term before.)

It might be helpful to add that the play is set in Eatonville, Florida (the same Black community that part of *Their Eyes Were Watching God* was set in), so I suspect that it's a dialect term from that particular time and place.

Comment: _Babes in Toyland_? Try checking full forms of BIT (I'd say mainly initialisms) in [_Acronym Finder_](https://www.acronymfinder.com/BIT.html).

Comment: The first thing that jumped into my mind was that B-I-T is the beginning of spelling out “bitch”. Whether this is a reasonable meaning in context I have no idea.

Comment: Is Teet male or female? Who is the letter from? Using "my bitch" as a term for a girlfriend, wife, or other partner (including perhaps a gay male lover), is fairly long-established, although certainly not polite.

Comment: FWIW, @9:15 and ff. in this video, the characters spell it out Bee, Aye, Tee.  https://youtu.be/LUHw5R8IyHA

Comment: I added some more context on the passage. Teet is female, and the letter is from a male, so that might add some color.

Comment: Probably Gullah

Comment: I thought maybe [***boyfriend in tow,***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22boyfriend+in+tow%22+), but that's a [relatively new term,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boyfriend+in+tow&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) so it won't do for a 90-year-old text.

Comment: The most detailed dictionary of twentieth-century African American slang that I'm aware of is Clarence Major, _Juba to Jive: A Dictionary of African-American Slang_ (1994). It has no entry for "B-I-T-sweetie" or for "B.I.T."—nor does it have any phrase entries in the "B" section that start with the initials "B"-"I"-"T". There is an entry for "B.O.T." (short for "balance of [imprisonment] time"), but Major states that this slang abbreviation did not come into use until the 1950s. I haven't been able to find any information anywhere on the term "B-I-T-sweetie" that appears in _The Mule-Bone_.

Comment: I’m eyeing ***Bit**-O-Honey*: [“an American candy product; it first appeared in 1928”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-O-Honey) for clues.

Comment: It's almost certainly a diversion of "B-I-T-C-H", a way of saying bitch in (relatively) polite society. It's a joke similar to what TV Tropes calls [Curse Cut Short](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CurseCutShort/SelfInterruption), first cousin of [subverted rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subverted_rhyme) like "Miss Suzie had a steamboat,/the steamboat had a bell,/Miss Suzie went to heaven,/the steamboat went to/Hello operator..." But until I can find examples of this, it must remain a comment.

Comment: Is it really plausible that a female character would refer to her male love interest as her "bitch"?

Comment: Sweet innocent Steve! It's a derogatory term, but I can imagine it might be used by some people; would depend on closer knowledge of the play and characters.

Answer (score -2):

From the context, what seems the the most likely is a specific but possibly not established acronym - yielding "butterflies in tummy" or "boyfriend in training", or "before interest and taxes", to indicate they're a prospect for personal interest and taxation. "Broomstick important target/interest trigger". "Bachelor in touch". "Best in town", the figurative one. Some of these sound more too modern than others, but they're to appeal to the modern people reading this, because eschewing a vivid unfolding may have been the crux of the original intention.

But it also could be a mode of referencing men in that situation by quoting the phrase they would use themselves to describe it from their point of view. Like Mister "Come here, dear". And the phrase, as Stuart F suggests, could be an ironing-out facetious impoliteness, if the word "bitch" made comical sense for the group.

Maybe the desired effect is a resonance of some of the above, but if I had to vote, I'd go with the butterflies.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,... If it's a letter from a prospective 'suiter' the capitalized letters with a period in between would say it's an anchcroymn and I'd think it to be 'Boyfriend in Training' as well.

Comment: Super solution. Now all you have to do to complete your answer is to add a link. Show us there is support for this educated guess, not your personal idea.

Comment: Also already given in another answer answer also as speculation.